# MySQLi connection to database as custom function in a separate PHP file

Tags: php, function, mysqli, include, prepared-statement

Having some issues with a piece of PHP code that I'm using to learn about it a little more.

I have the following situation:

**conf.php** file with database connection details

```php
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "mydatabase";
?>
```

**functions.php** file where I (hope to) store some functions to reuse in different pages

```php
<?php
function dbconnect() {
    global $dbhost;
    global $dbuser;
    global $dbpass;
    global $dbname;
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit('Error connecting to database');
    }
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli->set_charset("latin1_swedish_ci");
}
?>
```

**complete.php** file which receives some data through POST from another PHP page.

```php
<?php
    require_once( 'conf.php' );
    require_once( 'functions.php' );
?>
// some HTML code
<?php
    $mydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    dbconnect();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $_POST['field1'], $_POST['field2'], $_POST['field3'], $_POST['field4'], $_POST['field5'], $_POST['field6'], $_POST['field7'], $_POST['field8'], $mydate);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

If I send data through POST from my first page to **complete.php** I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null
>
> Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

For the first one I THINK I can get rid of by setting

```php
global $mysqli;
```

before **dbconnect();** in **complete.php**. I understand that this is because the function is coming from a different file, and I have to set the variables as **global**. This is why I set **$dbhost**, **$dbuser**, **$dbpass** and **$dbname** as GLOBAL in **conf.php**. Without them being set as global the application could not find the variables. I initially though that maybe I'm not using require_once correctly, and maybe that I should use require, include or include_once. But none of them made any difference. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

So after setting $mysqli as global the first error goes away, but I still get the other two errors.

If I replace **dbconnect();** in **complete.php** with

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit('Error connecting to database');
    }
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli->set_charset("latin1_swedish_ci");
```

basically the same thing from functions.php minus setting the variables as global, it works just fine and the data is added into the database.

I don`t know what I`m doing wrong, maybe something with the **require_once** function as the code works fine when the connection is written directly into complete.php, or maybe I`m not creating the function properly.
I`d like to add the prepared db insert statement as a separate function in functions.php as well, and just call it with add_data(); but at this point I`m not even getting to the issues I`ll face there. :)

Comment: You need `global $mysqli;` in `dbconnect()`.

Comment: @Barmar I initially added global $mysqli;to the end of dbconnect(), just before the closing }, and it didn't work. Since you saw the problem there, I tried adding it with the other variables set as global, and it worked great. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. You`re awesome!

Comment: I think it needs to be at the beginning, with all the other `global` statements.

Comment: You also need it if you try to use `$mysqli` in any other functions.